# How to do unique combinatorics with Laravel Factory

Tags: laravel, eloquent, factory, laravel-factory

I am trying to make a browser game in Laravel, and having some trouble with understanding the documentation for factories.

So this is the situation, each hero has possible 5 skills. But the hero will be only assigned randomly 3 of the 5 skills.

```
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,2,5
2,3,4
2,3,5
3,4,5
```

Instead of duplicating the factory 6 times is there a way for it to create these unique combos?

```
Hero::factory()->create([
    'hero_class' => 'Warrior',
    'attribute_health' => 100,
    'attribute_attack' => 35,
    'attribute_armor' => 75,
    'attribute_speed' => 22,
    'attribute_crit' => 15,
    'skill_1' => 1,
    'skill_2' => 1,
    'skill_3' => 1,
]);
```

I saw in docs you can do sequences

```
$users = User::factory()
                ->count(10)
                ->state(new Sequence(
                    ['admin' => 'Y'],
                    ['admin' => 'N'],
                ))
                ->create();
```

However, is there some more dynamic way in case I have more skill combos and don't want to manually type out 50 arrays?

To do the simple combos I had to do this

```
Hero::factory(5)
          ->state(new Sequence(
              [ 'skill_1' => 1, 'skill_2' => 2, 'skill_3' => 3, ],
              [ 'skill_1' => 1, 'skill_2' => 2, 'skill_3' => 4, ],
              [ 'skill_1' => 1, 'skill_2' => 2, 'skill_3' => 5, ],
              [ 'skill_1' => 2, 'skill_2' => 3, 'skill_3' => 4, ],
              [ 'skill_1' => 2, 'skill_2' => 3, 'skill_3' => 5, ],
              [ 'skill_1' => 3, 'skill_2' => 4, 'skill_3' => 5, ],
          ))
          ->create([
          'hero_class' => 'Warrior',
          'attribute_health' => 100,
          'attribute_attack' => 35,
          'attribute_armor' => 75,
          'attribute_speed' => 22,
          'attribute_crit' => 15,
      ]);
```

Any insight on how to go about this is much appreciated ;)

Comment: What is the purpose of using the factory? Are you creating these models for testing, or seeding the database? Where are you calling `Hero::factory()` as shown in your question?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am trying to seed the database, so I can run a simulation to see how the various classes perform in battle in all permutations in order to tweak traits, skills to create balance and eliminate any extreme bias towards one setup

Comment: Well guess you don't want another answer, but your database tables are poorly configured. You should have skills in a separate table, a pivot table between them, and the random assignment of skills to user should be done in the factory.

Comment: I am confused by what your question is? I am newbie to laravel and coding in general, don't really know how a lot of this stuff works. I just been doing has many relationship stuff bc I get lost with the pivot tables with how to do the queries

Comment: Think about what happens when you want your hero to have 5 skills. You have to change your entire table structure. Same for attributes; what if you want to add défense or something? So you set up a skills table with all the skills. A pivot table (`user_skill`) record would hold a `user_id` and a `skill_id`, rather than having this fixed in columns. It’s called database normalization if you want a search term to do some reading up on it. On the Laravel side you’d set up `Skill` as a new model with a relation to `Hero`.

Comment: Aah that makes more sense haha, tytyty for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, is first create some random, unique combinations of skills in an array:

```
$skills = [];
do { 
    $randomSkillSet = [
        'skill_1' => rand(1, 5), 
        'skill_2' => rand(1, 5), 
        'skill_3' => rand(1, 5)
    ];

    if (!in_array($randomSkillSet, $skills)) {
        $skills[] = $randomSkillSet;
    }
} while (count($skills) < 50);
// We make sure 50 is less than 5^3 = 125
```

Now you can use this array with unique skillsets in your Sequence, by taking each item from the `$skills` array in a Sequence closure, like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Sequence;

Hero::factory(50)
    ->state(new Sequence(
        function ($sequence) use ($skills) {
            return $skills[$sequence->index];
        }
    ))
 ->create([
    'hero_class' => 'Warrior',
    'attribute_health' => 100,
    'attribute_attack' => 35,
    'attribute_armor' => 75,
    'attribute_speed' => 22,
    'attribute_crit' => 15,
]);
```

This is possible because we can use the index property of the sequence instance that is injected into the closure.